# What is the maximum allowable building height in Mountain View, California?

Tags: california

Anecdotal evidence online suggests that the maximum height allowed by city code in Mountain View is 40 or 50 ft. Is there an authoritative source for this (or the correct) figure?

I've looked at [Muni-code](https://www2.municode.com/library/ca/mountain_view/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=PTIITHCO_CH8BU_ARTIBUCO_DIVICABUCO_S8.10.25SE905.3.1AMEI) without much luck.